# How to set the landing page for user after login with django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have the following in my project's urls.py:

```
path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
path('survey/',include(('survey.urls','survey'), namespace='survey')),
```

In my project's setting.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='survey/'
```

When I am on the login page of my application and click to submit. Instead of getting http://localhost:8000/survey/
and being redirected to the home page of my application, I am getting: http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/survey/ that gives this error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in TestAllAuth.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    accounts/ signup/ [name='account_signup']
    accounts/ login/ [name='account_login']
    accounts/ logout/ [name='account_logout']
    accounts/ password/change/ [name='account_change_password']
    accounts/ password/set/ [name='account_set_password']
    accounts/ inactive/ [name='account_inactive']
    accounts/ email/ [name='account_email']
    accounts/ confirm-email/ [name='account_email_verification_sent']
    accounts/ ^confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$ [name='account_confirm_email']
    accounts/ password/reset/ [name='account_reset_password']
    accounts/ password/reset/done/ [name='account_reset_password_done']
    accounts/ ^password/reset/key/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<key>.+)/$ [name='account_reset_password_from_key']
    accounts/ password/reset/key/done/ [name='account_reset_password_from_key_done']
    accounts/ social/
    survey/
    ontoSecConRule/


The current path, accounts/login/usecase/, didn't match any of these.
```

As you can see the usecase/ path is in the error message, but I am not reaching.

Where do I set the page (url) after a user has been authenticated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('survey:the_name_of_url')
```

for redirecting you can use this method, since namespace is given you have to mention it.

Comment: Thank you, this is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured what was the issue.

I replaced LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='survey/' with LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/survey/'